# Add EBS to Ubuntu EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm having problem connecting EBS volume to my Ubuntu EC2 Instance.

Here's what I did:

1. From the Amazon AWS Console, I created a EBS 150GB volume and attached it to an Ubuntu 11.10 EC2 instance. Under the EBS volume properties, "Attachment" shows: "[my Ubuntu instance id]:/dev/sdf (attached)"
2. Tried mounting the drive on the Ubuntu box, and it told me "mount: /dev/sdf is not a block device"

   `sudo mount /dev/sdf /vol`
3. So I checked with fdisk and tried to mount from the new location and it told me it wasn't the right file system.

   `sudo fdisk -l`

   `sudo mount -v -t ext4 /dev/xvdf /vol`

   the error:

   > mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf, missing
   >   codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info
   >   is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so

   "dmesg | tail" told me it gave the following error:

   > EXT4-fs (sda1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem

I also tried putting the configurations into /etc/fstab file as instructed on http://www.webmastersessions.com/how-to-attach-ebs-volume-to-amazon-ec2-instance, but still gave same not the right file system error.

Questions:

Q1: Based on point 1 (above), why was the volume mapped to 'dev/sdf' when it's really mapped to '/dev/xvdf'?

Q2: What else do I need to do to get the EBS volume loaded? I thought it'll just take care of everything for me when I attach it to a instance.

Comment: This may belong on a sysadmin-oriented StackExchange site.  Nevertheless exactly what I needed to find.  Thank you for asking this!

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Since this is a new volume, you need to format the EBS volume (block device) with a file system between step 1 and step 2. So the entire process with your sample mount point is:

1. Create EBS volume.
2. Attach EBS volume to `/dev/sdf` (EC2's external name for this particular device number).
3. Format file system `/dev/xvdf` (Ubuntu's internal name for this particular device number):

   ```
   sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf
   ```

   *Only format the file system if this is a new volume with no data on it. Formatting will make it difficult or impossible to retrieve any data that was on this volume previously.*
4. Mount file system (with update to /etc/fstab so it stays mounted on reboot):

   ```
   sudo mkdir -m 000 /vol
   echo "/dev/xvdf /vol auto noatime 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
   sudo mount /vol
   ```

Comment: Just to be explicit, /dev/xvdf doesn't exist prior to your mounting /dev/sdf.

Comment: @Dror: "mount" is a specific technical term that relates to step 4 and is only done with /dev/xvdf, the internal Ubuntu name for the device.  The /dev/sdf name is EC2's external name for this device and you must "attach" the EBS volume at that location (step 2) before you can format and mount it.

Comment: You're correct. The EBS attach is done externally, by AWS and is equivalent to attaching a USB device to a computer. The mount command is a linux/unix command that only works on formated file systems and connects the device /dev/xxx with the location in the file system e.g. /mnt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I was totally confused by the /mnt directory and wrongly assumed that my extra EBS volume (/dev/xvdf) that I told AWS to attach at instance creation was already mounted. Also, the mapping between what AWS shows (/dev/sdf) and (/dev/xvdf) that exists on ubuntu tripped me up.

Comment: @Dror @ankimal or @EricHammond - I followed the exact instructions here. However when I `cd` into `/vol` (or whatever I named it) I'm not getting the full size of the partition, and there is a strange folder called `lost+found` in there.  Know how I can get around this?

Comment: @Brandon: Please ask this as a new question on serverfault.com providing all the details of what you did instead of tacking it in a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately these are definitely not the right steps. EBS I have mounted actually has a public dataset on it and mkfs.ext4 will go and erase it. These things make sense if EBS was empty.

Comment: @scrapcodes: Fortunately, these are definitely the right steps for the original poster's question (new, unformatted EBS volume).  They certainly may not be the right steps if you have a completely different situation (EBS volume created from snapshot containing existing filesystem).

Comment: I agree, There is no solution actually, if filesystem is not detected automatically. Original question does not say anything about new drive.

Comment: Why does step four include the flag `-m 000`?

Comment: @JosephMornin Turning off all bits in the mode is a simple indicator that nobody should be allowed to do anything in this directory until a new file system is mounted here.  It's a message that this directory has been created as a mount point. It is not required for functionality, but sometimes avoids the mistakes of creating files when the desired volume is not mounted.

Comment: I have stopped an ec2 instance and after restart it the attached ebs volume is empty. I am facing the same problem for mounting it. Any idea?

Comment: @AlexandreRademaker: Comment threads are not the best place for new questions. Try creating a new question with all the details on serverfault.com

Comment: @EricHammond: just connect this answer to this blog: http://alestic.com/2010/02/ec2-resize-running-ebs-root. thanks man!

Answer (score -5):

Step 1: create volume 
step 2: attach to your instance root volume
step 3: run sudo resize 2fs -p /dev/xvde 
step 4: restart apache2 sudo service apache2 restart
 
step 4: run df -h

You can see total volume attached to your instance.