# Trouble Mounting EBS Volume on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount, amazon-ebs

Good afternoon,

I am new to EC2 and have been trying to mount an EBS volume on an EC2 instance.  Following the instructions at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535617/add-ebs-to-ubuntu-ec2-instance) I did the following:

```
1.  Format file system /dev/xvdf (Ubuntu's internal name for this particular device number):

  sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf

2.  Mount file system (with update to /etc/fstab so it stays mounted on reboot):

  sudo mkdir -m 000 /vol
  echo "/dev/xvdf /vol auto noatime 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
  sudo mount /vol
```

There now appears to be a folder (or volume) at `/vol` but it has been (prepopulated?) with a folder entitled `lost+found`, and does not have the 15GB that I assigned to the EBS volume (it has something much smaller).

Any help you could provide would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

After following the first suggestion (`sudo mount /dev/xvdf /vol`), here is the output of df:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8256952 791440   7046084  11% /
udev              294216      8    294208   1% /dev
tmpfs             120876    164    120712   1% /run
none                5120      0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              302188      0    302188   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdf       15481840 169456  14525952   2% /vol
```

This might indicate that I do in fact have the 15GB on `/vol` .  However I still do have that strange `lost+found` folder in there.  Anything I should be worried about?

Comment: what is the output of the command `df`?

Comment: See info in an update in my question body.

Comment: What makes you think that you don't have the requested 15G ?

Comment: @Brandon lost+found is a directory created when you initialize (read format) a volume with Ext4, nothing to worry abouth there. Your *df* output looks like you have 15GB volume. Perhaps you need *df -h* for a human-readable output.

Comment: Thanks @rhetonik - looking like I"m ok!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your /vol. It was mounted as shown by `df` output.

`lost+found` directory is used by filesystem to recover broken files (fsck stores recovered files there), so it's normal you can see it.

Small size problem might refer to kibibytes:

```
1 kibibyte = 2^10 = 1024 bytes
16G = 14.9Gib
```

Answer (score 2):

Try at the last line:
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /vol

Comment: I get the same thing doing that :(

Comment: I've outputted the results of `df` in an update ... Maybe see if I'm worried about nothing?