# SSD drives not accessible in EC2 ubuntu Instances

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, solid-state-drive

In the following EC2 instance types which have SSD drives

- r3.2xlarge
- r3.4xlarge
- i2.xlarge

When I login through SSH, I am unable to see the SSD drives. I was trying "df -h".

I have tried

- reboot, but that did not help.
- tried to terminate and create a new instance that also does not help. Suggesting that its not one-off issue.

Comment: Where are you looking for them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found one solution by trying the steps suggested for adding [EBS volumes to Ubuntu instnaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535617/add-ebs-to-ubuntu-ec2-instance)

Below are my steps:

- sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
- sudo mkdir -m 000 /mnt # isnt required if /mnt exists.
- echo "/dev/xvdb /mnt auto noatime 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
- sudo mount /mnt