# Permission denied when accessing new EBS volume

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions

I'm new to AWS and EC2.

I just added a new EBS volume to my EC2 instance. I formatted and mounted it using instructions from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11537390/765287).

When I try to access the new volume I have permissions issues.  `cd /vol` gives me

```
-bash: cd: /vol: Permission denied
```

Does anyone know why I can't `cd` into the new volume?

In case it's relevant, `ls -l /vol` gives me

```
ls: cannot access /data/lost+found: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? lost+found
```

. `sudo ls -l /vol` returns

```
 total 16
 drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Sep 12 22:14 lost+found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You only have root access to the directory. Try `sudo chmod 777 /vol`.

Comment: Or become root using ```sudo -s```

Comment: Ok! running `sudo chmod 777 /vol` lets me write to the directory. Thanks you two. :)  If either of you put your comments into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 32):

you need to have rights to access the volume.

You may also take ownership of the volume, by doing in the console:

```
sudo chown `whoami` /vol
```

you may also change the rights with chmod. You may check documentation on chown and chmod linux commands.

Comment: Thank you  my good sir :). This should be the top answer!

Answer (score 5):

you need to change owner of the EBS volume.

Say you mounted the new EBS volume to `xvdf_mountpoint` folder.
first run `whoami` to get your account name
then switch to root: `su root`
type in the password. if password not set: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-change-root-linux/
`chown [account name] /dev/xvdf`
then    `su [account name]`
,then you have complete access to the newly mounted EBS volume.