# AWS mounting old volume from old instance to new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, mount

I did detach old volume from old instance and attach old volume to new instance in aws console.

and I followed this question: [Add EBS to Ubuntu EC2 Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535617/add-ebs-to-ubuntu-ec2-instance)

When I command `'sudo mount /vol'`

It shows me the error :

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>
> ```
>    In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>    dmesg | tail or so.
> ```

The output of `'dmesg | tail'` is below

> [    9.158108] audit: type=1400 audit(1481970181.964:8):
>   apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined"
>   name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=705
>   comm="apparmor_parser" [    9.158434] audit: type=1400
>   audit(1481970181.964:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load"
>   profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script"
>   pid=705 comm="apparmor_parser" [    9.178292] audit: type=1400
>   audit(1481970181.984:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load"
>   profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/lxc-start" pid=761
>   comm="apparmor_parser" [    9.341874] audit: type=1400
>   audit(1481970182.148:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load"
>   profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lxd/lxd-bridge-proxy" pid=763
>   comm="apparmor_parser" [   11.673698] random: nonblocking pool is
>   initialized [   11.766032] EXT4-fs (xvda1): resizing filesystem from
>   2094474 to 2095139 blocks [   11.766371] EXT4-fs (xvda1): resized
>   filesystem to 2095139 [   12.716500] cgroup: new mount options do not
>   match the existing superblock, will be ignored [  236.029463]
>   blkfront: xvdf: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants:
>   disabled; indirect descriptors: enabled; [  236.038716]  xvdf: xvdf1

Old volume Attachment information in AWS console is below :

```
VOLUME_ID (NEW_INSTANCE_NAME):/dev/sdf (attached)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your volume has a partition table, as evidenced by...

```
[ 236.038716] xvdf: xvdf1
```

...so you need to mount the partition, not the volume.

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /path/to/mount-point
```

You can also see this using `lsblk`.

Comment: Can you help me configuring boto s3?

Comment: You'll need to post this question separately, but please search the site, first.  There are many questions that already have answers.

Comment: Oh, I see you have already [posted it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41199723/1695906).

Comment: But I'm blocked in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201422/aws-boto-no-handler-after-configuration