# python manage.py collectstatic : boto.exception.S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-s3

**Hello all,**

I want to use a S3 bucket in Franckfurt or in London(eu-west-2).

I have an existing bucket in Oregon and create another in ireland. The django command "**python manage.py collectstatic**"  work well. Collectstatic comes from Django==1.10.5 (January 4, 2017) running on "windows 10" python 2.7

But when executing "python manage.py collectstatic" on a London or Frankfurt S3 bucket, i got the error :

> boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request.

refering to :

- [Using boto for AWS S3 Buckets for Signature V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400105/using-boto-for-aws-s3-buckets-for-signature-v4)
- [boto S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199723/boto-s3responseerror-400-bad-request)

So i did the followings :

- I create a ~.boto file and add 1 line: [s3] use-sigv4 = True.....failed
- I create a ~.boto\config file. Add 1 line: [s3] use-sigv4 = True.....failed
- I modified ~.aws\config file with region = eu-west-2...failed

Any suggestion ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a file named .boto in the directy c:\users\myname  or ~.boto

[Credentials]

aws_access_key_id = 'XXXXXXXXX'

aws_secret_access_key = 'XXXXXXX'

[s3]

host=s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

aws_access_key_id = 'XXXXXXXXX'

aws_secret_access_key = 'XXXXXXXXX'