# AWS BOTO : No handler After configuration

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm deploying my Django application on ec2 on AWS.

I did configuration setting up ~/.boto and finally succeed in 'python manage.py collectstatic'.

If there is an error, then error is caused! (I know because I solved it by setting up ~/.boto configuration file!).

But after configuration , when I query my image file at S3 mapped to my imageField model, it shows the error message below:

> No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked.
>   ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials

I think I made it authentication, but why is this message occuring?

Comment: You should launch your EC2 instance with an appropriate IAM role, rather than store credentials explicitly in boto's config file.

Comment: @jarmod Wow, I think i'm remembering a little. Should I assign IAM role to target instance?

Comment: @jarmod Can you show me some direction? please

Comment: See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4AyfV3Z3xs.

Answer (score 0):

Using a role is absolutely the correct way to handle authentication in EC2 to AWS.  Putting long term credentials on the machine is a disgusting alternative.  Assuming you're using a standard SDK, ( and boto absolutely is), the SDK will automatically use the role's temporary credentials to authenticate, so all you have to do is launch the instance with an "instance profile" specifying a role, and you get secure credentials delivery for free.

You'll have to replace your server to do so but_being able to recreate servers is fundamental to success in aws anyway.  The sooner you start thinking that way, the better the cloud will work for you.

Once the role is attached to the instance, the policies defining the role's permission can be modified dynamically.  So you don't need to get the permissions sorted out before creating the role.

At the high level, you specify a role at instance creation time.  The EC2 console can facilitate the process of creating a role, allowing the EC2 service to access it, and specifying at instance creation time.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html provides detailed instructions.