# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at / debug_toolbar/base.html after deployiing to EC2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, django-settings

I am trying to deploy a Django app on EC2 Instance. I had put my EC2 instance in the Allowed_Host correctly. but it kept giving me a Disallowed_Host error. I have been trying to fix that but Now I get the.

> Django TemplateDoesNotExist at /  debug_toolbar/base.html Error

***Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong?*** Below are my screenshots and code. By the way it works perfectly fine in my development 127.0.0.1

[image]

> Also below is the Traceback just in case

[image]

I have attached my settings.py file below

```
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "1111111111111111111111"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["ec2-11-111-111-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com", "127.0.0.1", "Siteevent.com", "www.Siteevent.com"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'bootstrap3',
    'accounts',
    'groups',
    'posts',
    'proof',
    'feeds',
    'questions',
    'tasting',
    'verification',
    'cart',
    'stripe',
    'order',
    'report',
    'django_cleanup',
    'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
    'social_django',
    'storages',
    'captcha',


]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'accounts.authentication.EmailAuthBackend',

]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'order', 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
                'cart.context_processors.counter',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'Site_event',
        'USER': '11111111111111111111111',
        'PASSWORD': '11111111111111111111111111',
        'HOST': 'Site-event1111111111111111111111111rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

# TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
TIME_ZONE = "America/New_York"
USE_TZ = True

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.MediaStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'Site-media-1111111111111'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'aws_storage_classes.StaticStorage'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_S3_DOMAIN = "%s.s3.amazonaws.com" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME


STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/static/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/media/' % AWS_S3_DOMAIN

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'loggedin'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'accounts:login'

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH_SECRET = '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'


INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', )

BOOTSTRAP3 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%b %d %Y']

TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%I:%M %p']

####Stripe Settings###

STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = '11111111111111111111111111111111111'
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = '11111111111111111111111111111111111'


RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = "11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = "111111111111111111111111111111"


# try:
#     from Site.local_settings import *
# except ImportError as e:
#     pass
#
```

Adding django_toolbar to the INSTALED_APPS gives the error below

[image]

I even tried removing the django_tooldbar and the middleare involved that gave me a same error just at a different place

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error is occurring because you have included `debug_toolbar` in middleware but not in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. So either you need to remove `'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',` from `MIDDLEWARE`.

**OR** add `debug_toolbar` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Reference to [django_toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: I tried both your suggestions I get a `No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials` error see image above

Comment: @MarcoBianchi I think you can look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201422/aws-boto-no-handler-after-configuration

Comment: thanks your solution resolved my debug_toolbar issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

But for me that was caused by INTERNAL_IPS.

When it is set to : `INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1', ]` and trying access http://localhost:8000/ that doesn't work, neither with ip adress.

But if it is turned to : `INTERNAL_IPS = ['localhost', ]` that works fine with both http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and http://localhost:8000/.

Comment: Do you actually see the toolbar? In my case 'localhost' just disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the **Django Debud Tool Bar** from installed apps, you have to remove it from **MiddleWares** section too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).